# cmd console output to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I have some tool which is outputs some data directly to console output.

I want to save this output to some variable and then pass it somewhere else...

Is it possible to do?

Example:

```
rem this outputs String1 values from myfile.txt
GetString myfile.txt String1
rem I want this value for example in %p% variable, and then:
call MyApp %p%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
for /f %%a in ('GetString myfile.txt') do call MyApp %%a
```

Although I'm not really sure what you mean about the `String1` bit, if this isn't right, can you clarify?

Comment: String1 means something like: String1='Value that I needed'. I.e. The GetString myfile.txt String1 gives me 'Value that I needed' into output. Nice idea to use for. I was thinking about that. But, like Christian said for has it's own issues sometimes... But thanks, maybe that one will suit me!

Comment: +1, though no need for p variable. `for /f %%a in ('GetString myfile.txt') do call MyApp %%a`

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I would advice to follow @Balic C's answer as it works without temporary files. Nevertheless the `for` command has it's issues (or at least can be hard to get right) when the command or the arguments, or both, contain spaces and you need to handle proper quoting.

In such a case you could also store the output of the tool in a temporary file and then read it into a variable using `set /P`:

```
set temp_file=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp
GetString myfile.txt > "%temp_file%"
set /P p=<"%temp_file%"

call MyApp %p%

del /F "%temp_file%"
```

Comment: Nice option too. Thank you! ..Oh. Now it's hard to decide which answer is the best :)

Comment: Again, I would first try @BaliC's approach. As it works without temporary files.