# Tail a logfile using batch and match for string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to tail a logfile using batch script. The file gets updated continuously, so I need to match keywords to the updates in file. How can I do this. I tried tailing a file like this

powershell -command "& {Get-Content -Path "C:\scripts\test.txt" -Wait}"

If anyone has any idea, do let me know

Comment: There are [lots of similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+tail+answers%3A1) on stackoverflow ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136733/unix-tail-and-grep-equivalent-for-windows) for example). Have you actually used search? If yes, please specify in your question what problem do you have with applying the existing solutions.

Comment: I have definitely used google search (common sense)

Comment: I have definitely used google search (common sense based on the powershell command I posted in the question i posted)
I have used tail.exe program to achieve this. I actually want to use a bat file instead of a .exe to achieve this. I used tailhead from the link but didnt work for me.

P.S. google searches of the same question phrased differently gives different answers. Can't be blamed for phrasing differently. But a person like me will definitely search first and ask next. Its become a common response to pathetically ask someone if they did a search. Thanks for responding

Comment: Read FAQ. To make the question legit you must mention what previous solutions you have used and how it didn't work. The simplest form of `tail` using powershell is `powershell -c "Get-Content test.txt -Tail 1"`. If that's not enough information for you then edit the question and specify what the output should be, maybe add some minimal examples of a log file and output.

Comment: Thanks. How do I assign the output value of this powershell command to a variable?

Comment: Use the [standard way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600856/cmd-console-output-to-variable). It seems this time you haven't used search :-)

Comment: The -tail doesn't work. It doesn't work for powershell <V3

Comment: Well, install ps4 or use pure batch tail.

Comment: I used this:
powershell -command "& {Get-Content file.txt | Select-Object -last 100}"  and it worked. I can't upgrade my clients powershell. So I looked hard for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Master,

You can try tail to the log file by searching for a particular string/event-

```
tail .\filename.log | findstr -i "string/event"
```